# Add md5 hash to file URL for optimal caching in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, hash, md5

Appending a file's hash to its url seems like a common thing to do to ensure files can have infinitely far cache expiration dates without causing problems when a new version of the file is available.

How is this task usually accomplished in Node.js?

### Being clearer

Instead of asking the browser to load `main.js`, I would ask for `main.085cc38ce00780e9365ee07275bfb8d8.js`, where `085cc38ce00780e9365ee07275bfb8d8` is the file hash. So that when I change the content of my main file, the hash will also change and it will be as if the HTML were requesting a completely different file.

The solution I'm looking for must tackle:

- Renaming the file or mapping the name-with-hash to name-without-hash
- If files are renamed, getting my HTML markup to reference the correct file name with hash.

For context: My current build pipeline uses Gulp and docker, so I rebuild everything on every change, but I am open for any solution.

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev; create a function for use in your templates that reads the manifest it produces. (https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/blob/master/integration.md)

Comment: @Ryan awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you want to write that as an answer rather than a comment?